# Cannot iterate over a key/value array in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iteration, each

I have an array in the following form:

```
[
   849D7F716C80E6FBA1B6C984AC671CFA6BA19BEF: Array[7],
   13C29365E98124E760AE090047358D2C76C82D4C: Array[7],
   1165565F4A1EDB8DD07E617D56F73BF81F9CB184: Array[7], 
   F12A4A88F71EC50751D3E11F4AA331699CDED76: Array[8]
]
```

The sub arrays are objects:

```
3F12A4A88F71EC50751D3E11F4AA331699CDED76: Array[8] >
  0: Object
  1: Object
  2: Object
  3: Object
  4: Object
  5: Object
  6: Object
  7: Object
```

I can see it on my console using

```
console.log(arr);
```

But if I do this:

```
$.each(arr, function (key, value)
{
    console.log(key);
    console.log(value);
});
```

Nothing happens. Why?! It should print something like this:

```
> 849D7F716C80E6FBA1B6C984AC671CFA6BA19BEF
> Array[7]
> 13C29365E98124E760AE090047358D2C76C82D4C
> Array[7]
> 1165565F4A1EDB8DD07E617D56F73BF81F9CB184
> Array[7]
> F12A4A88F71EC50751D3E11F4AA331699CDED76
> Array[8]
```

Comment: Your for each function doesn't have any values instantiated named `a` or `b`.

Comment: a and b do not exist... you are literally logging non existent variables. Try `console.log(key)` or `console.log(value)`

Comment: How is the array populated? Hardcoded values?

Comment: *nothing* happens? are you sure? No errors in your console or anything?

Comment: @Jamiec ha ha ha...!

Comment: Just nothing guys... a and b were just a typo, sorry!

Comment: @Jai - did I say something funny? It was not meant to be, it was a serious question.

Comment: Array is populated with hashes/arrays like this: arr[hash] = currentarr. If I right click on the console after logging the array (which works fine) and tell him to store it as a temporari variable I get an empty array -_-

Comment: @Jamiec ah! Not like that but the way you wrote _nothing happens?_....just lost control when i saw it in context of question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
[
   849D7F716C80E6FBA1B6C984AC671CFA6BA19BEF: Array[7],
   13C29365E98124E760AE090047358D2C76C82D4C: Array[7],
   1165565F4A1EDB8DD07E617D56F73BF81F9CB184: Array[7], 
   F12A4A88F71EC50751D3E11F4AA331699CDED76: Array[8]
]
```

Is not a valid syntax for array initialisation. Array elements do not have key/values they just have values - perhaps you meant to create an object literal:

```
{
   849D7F716C80E6FBA1B6C984AC671CFA6BA19BEF: Array[7],
   13C29365E98124E760AE090047358D2C76C82D4C: Array[7],
   1165565F4A1EDB8DD07E617D56F73BF81F9CB184: Array[7], 
   F12A4A88F71EC50751D3E11F4AA331699CDED76: Array[8]
}
```

Once you do it that way, your code works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/veky1dk5/

Answer (score 1):

make it as json array and then use each like

```
[ {  '849D7F716C80E6FBA1B6C984AC671CFA6BA19BEF': Array[7],


'13C29365E98124E760AE090047358D2C76C82D4C': Array[7],


'1165565F4A1EDB8DD07E617D56F73BF81F9CB184': Array[7], 


'F12A4A88F71EC50751D3E11F4AA331699CDED76': Array[8] }]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a and b in console. Use key and value in printing console:

```
$.each(arr, function (key, value)
{
    console.log(key);
    console.log(value);
});
```

Comment: Sorry it was a typo! 'T_T